No sound ouput device after upgrading from 22.04 to 24.04
My computer was running well prior to upgrading from Jammy Jellyfish to Noble Numbat.  I am experiencing many problems with slow boot, large lag time for applications to launch, right clicking on any screen causes 1-2 minute delay on all apps, and no sound output devices.  While the slowness is a hassle, the no sound makes it unusable for many of the things I use my desktop for, meetings, listening to music, youtube, etc.
I have read many posts on this topic, but none of the offered solutions seem to apply to my situation.
As a troubleshooting step, I downloaded 24.04.1 to a USB memory stick and "tried" 24.04.1 running from the memory stick.  This seemed to clear up all of my lagginess and sound issues.
Here is some basic information that I hope is helpful.

I have recently upgraded from 22.04 to 24.04.

$ uname --all
Linux gearset-ii 6.8.0-41-generic #41-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Fri Aug  2 20:41:06 UTC 2024 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux


The problem is discovered by running Settings -> Sound -> Output Device shows No Output Devices.

My computer has a multitude of output devices.  See below for example.  I normally use the last device shown by aplay.


$ aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 3: HDMI 0 [MSI G271]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: Generic [HD-Audio Generic], device 3: HDMI 0 [MSI G271]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: Generic [HD-Audio Generic], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: Generic_1 [HD-Audio Generic], device 0: ALC892 Analog [ALC892 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
$ 

$ lspci | grep -i Audio
10:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GP107GL High Definition Audio Controller (rev a1)
2b:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Raven/Raven2/Fenghuang HDMI/DP Audio Controller
2b:00.6 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h/19h HD Audio Controller
$ 

$ sudo dmesg | grep -i audio
[   29.228162] snd_hda_intel 0000:10:00.1: Handle vga_switcheroo audio client
[   29.273257] input: HD-Audio Generic HDMI/DP,pcm=3 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:2b:00.1/sound/card1/input23
[   29.273615] input: HD-Audio Generic HDMI/DP,pcm=7 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:2b:00.1/sound/card1/input24
[   29.283336] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC2D0: autoconfig for ALC892: line_outs=1 (0x14/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0) type:line
[   29.283343] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC2D0:    speaker_outs=0 (0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[   29.283347] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC2D0:    hp_outs=1 (0x1b/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[   29.283351] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC2D0:    mono: mono_out=0x0
[   29.283353] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC2D0:    inputs:
[   29.283356] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC2D0:      Front Mic=0x19
[   29.283359] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC2D0:      Rear Mic=0x18
[   29.283362] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC2D0:      Line=0x1a
[   29.301275] input: HD-Audio Generic Front Mic as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:2b:00.6/sound/card2/input29
[   29.301438] input: HD-Audio Generic Rear Mic as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:2b:00.6/sound/card2/input30
[   29.301548] input: HD-Audio Generic Line as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:2b:00.6/sound/card2/input31
[   29.301666] input: HD-Audio Generic Line Out as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:2b:00.6/sound/card2/input32
[   29.301779] input: HD-Audio Generic Front Headphone as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:2b:00.6/sound/card2/input33
[   32.789667] snd_hda_intel 0000:2b:00.1: bound 0000:2b:00.0 (ops amdgpu_dm_audio_component_bind_ops [amdgpu])

I am not able to interpret the information I have provided, so the problem may be staring me in the face.  If you need something else, please let me know.
This upgrade has gone horribly wrong, and I am hoping I can get some advice on what to do next.
Thanks,
John

I have read forum posts saying kernel 6.8.0-41 has a known problem with AMD.  Can anyone confirm?

The daily updates have brought me a new kerel, but the problem remains unchanged.$ uname -a
Linux gearset-ii 6.8.0-44-generic #44-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Tue Aug 13 13:35:26 UTC 2024 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Confirm. Please refer to here  All we seem to be able to do is wait. Your sound issue is unrelated to this. I had the same thing after the 24.04 update. Something about the configs and devices in alsa and pulseaudio. sorry i can't be more precise but look at "solutions" offered on Google. Confirm tediously slow boot-up also. Something odd about 24.04, I feel . . . At least you have kernel 6.8.0-44 - not 6.8.0-41 and stuck there despite updates offering 6.8.0-44 but fails.

Could you fix it? If so, please share here (and tag me).
